# Obtaining asymptotics of parametrically defined function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How do I get small-$x$ behavio of $y=f(x)$ when the function is defined parametrically in terms of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ below?

$$x(\text{t$$})\text{=}\frac{\sin ^{n+1}((n+1) t)}{\sin (t) \sin ^n(n t)}\\ y(\text{t})\text{=}\frac{\sin ^2(t) \sin ^{n-1}(n t)}{\pi  \sin ^n((n+1) t)}\\t\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{n + 1}\right)$$

For special case of $n=1$ I know the following:

$$y\sim \frac{1}{\pi  \sqrt{x}}$$

Obtained using the following command

`Assuming[{x > 0},  Asymptotic[PDF[MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1], x], x -> 0]]`

How do I get it for other values of $n$?

```
x[t_] := Sin[(n + 1) t]^(n + 1)/(Sin[t] Sin[n t]^n);
y[t_] := (Sin[t]^2 Sin[n t]^(n - 1))/(\[Pi] Sin[(n + 1) t]^n);

clip[a_] := Clip[a, {0, Pi/(n + 1)}];
nvals = Range[3];
SF = StringForm;
legends = SF["n=``", #] & /@ nvals;
funcs = Table[{x@clip@t, y@clip@t}, {n, nvals}];
parametric = 
 ParametricPlot @@ {funcs, {t, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 1}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    "Squared singular value density, product of n Gaussian matrices", 
   PlotLegends -> legends}
```

[image]

This is formula 3.61 of Ipsen's [thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.06128.pdf). $n=2$ expression has closed form expression of $y$ in terms of $x$ in Eq.35 of Burda free products [paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/473/1/012002/pdf), this appears too hard for Mathematica to solve. Simple expressions for higher $n$ appear not known.

Comment: I was looking for something of the form $y=C x^{-n/(n+1)}$

Comment: @yarchik either one works, but I'm curious for solution for general $n>1$

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at my solution? It is only MA-assisted, not fully automatic, but I believe it completely answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the question is so simple that no help of Mathematica is needed. Anyway, denote
$$
\alpha = \sin(\pi+(n+1)\epsilon).
$$
For $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, it follows $\alpha\rightarrow 0$ and thus $x\rightarrow 0$. Then, in the vicinity of $\epsilon=0$ we have in the leading order
$$
x=\frac{\alpha^{n+1}}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)\sin^n\left(\frac{n\pi}{n+1}\right)},\\
y=\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)\sin^{n-1}\left(\frac{n\pi}{n+1}\right)}{\pi \alpha^{n}}.
$$
This allows one to express
$$
y(x\sim 0)\sim\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)\sin^{n-1}\left(\frac{n\pi}{n+1}\right)}{\pi [\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)\sin^n\left(\frac{n\pi}{n+1}\right)]^{n/(n+1)}}\frac{1}{x^{n/(n+1)}}.
$$

Now we can use $\sin(\frac{n\pi}{n+1})=\sin(\frac{\pi}{n+1})$ in order to get

```
c = Sin[Pi/(n + 1)]^2 Sin[n*Pi/(n + 1)]^(n - 1)/(Sin[Pi/(n + 1)]*Sin[n*Pi/(n + 1)]^n)^(n/(n + 1))*1/Pi*1/x^(n/(n + 1));
FullSimplify[c /. {Sin[(Pi *n )/(1 + n)] -> Sin[Pi/(1 + n)]}, 
 Assumptions -> n > 0]
```

this compact answer
$$
\boxed{y(x\sim 0)\sim\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)\frac{1}{\pi x^{n/(n+1)}}.}
$$

Comment: thanks, it appears to be correct, I guess need to wait for future Mathematica version to automate this

Answer (score 1):

You may write dy/dx = (dy/dt) / (dx/dt). With this we get:

```
x[t_] := Sin[(n + 1) t]^(n + 1)/(Sin[t] Sin[n t]^n);
y[t_] := (Sin[t]^2 Sin[n t]^(n - 1))/(\[Pi] Sin[(n + 1) t]^n);
slope[t_] = y'[t]/x'[t] // Simplify;
```

Now we take the limit t->0:

```
slope[t] /. t -> 0
```

[image]

This was to be expected considering your plots.

Comment: I was actually looking for an equivalent of `Asymptotic` rather than `Limit`

Comment: The asymptote would be a vertical line and this is not a function. Therefore it does not exist.

Comment: For $n=1$ the asymptotic behavior can be obtained as follows: `Assuming[{x > 0}, 
 Asymptotic[PDF[MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1], x], x -> 0]]`